# some apps/popups displayed in gnome-style in ubuntu 14.04 (unity)

Tags: unity, gnome, dialog

after installing [valama](https://github.com/Valama/valama), some dialogs ([open-dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVEiy.png), save-dialog, password-prompt, ...),  are displayed in gnome-style (no title-bar). this issue appears in any application using gnome-dialogs (i.g. gedit)

does anyone know how to fix that?

thank you!

Comment: Is this a problem of only one or of all users? I have the same problem at only one user and only with `nautilus`

Comment: This issue happens to the guest user as well.

Comment: hmm interesting.

Comment: I've installed kubuntu-desktop next to the unity desktop a couple of days ago and window style leaks from the kubuntu into unity. I tried this on a virtual machine also with same result, so it's a thing..

Comment: hmmm, we had (maybe at 10.10) ubuntu gnome(there was no unity), then we distupgraded until 12.04. Then we transferred the system to a new machine and distupgraded here to 14.04.